# Highchart strange behavior of Range selector text boxes.

Tags: javascript, highcharts

On the following [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kami924/aw31ddvv/1/) I have formatted the date as '%d-%m-%Y'. On change of date inside the text box, I was hoping that the navigator will move to the selected date but the navigator is moved to the start of data.

If this code `inputDateFormat: '%d-%m-%Y'` is removed. Then Its ok But I want the date format as `%d-%m-%Y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because `Date.parse` doesn't understand the `dd-mm-yyyy` notation.
See the docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.inputEditDateFormat

> This must be a format that is recognized by JavaScript Date.parse

I added a simple `inputDateParser` function inside the `rangeSelector` object, which seems to work:

```
inputDateParser: function(value) {
  var date = value.split('-');
  var returnDate = new Date(
    parseInt(date[2], 10), 
    parseInt(date[1], 10) - 1, 
    parseInt(date[0], 10) + 1
  ).getTime();

  return returnDate;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aw31ddvv/6/

Comment: This seems to change the month though. Date()'s month entry is 0-based so you need to account for that.